# Node builder stops working on IBM travis

Tags: travis-ci

We have had our node project synced with the IBM version of Travis (https://travis.ibm.com/) for CI but it now refuses to do the build with the following error message, thoughts?

`Starting with io.js 3 and Node.js 4, building native extensions requires C++11-compatible compiler, which seems unavailable on this VM. Please read https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Node.js-v4-(or-io.js-v3)-compiler-requirements.`

when adding the requirements as listed in the url, I get the following errors

`Disallowing sources: ubuntu-toolchain-r-test`

Answer (score 1):

the following code solved the issue:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
    - "5.4.1"

env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - sourceline: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test'
    packages:
      - g++-4.8
```